# HTML & Javascript Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been playing around and learning coding for about 2 months now and was looking into coding a website with a fullscreen image slider. However, have tried searching on the web for solutions to no avail.

I would like to check if it's possible to change the image sourcing from a URL to sourcing from local disk and how do I do that? Have tried using the HTML methods as well but Dreamweaver had notified for syntax error.

Below is a JavaScript code in HTML.

```js
<!-- Script for Image Background -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/supersized.3.2.7.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slideshow_theme/supersized.shutter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $.supersized({
            // Functionality
            slide_interval: 10000,    // Length between transitions
            transition: 1,            // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
            transition_speed: 1000,   // Speed of transition

            // Components
            slide_links: 'blank',     // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
            slides: [                 // Slideshow Images
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-2.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-2.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-3.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-3.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-1.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-1.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/' },
                { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/' }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, probably just replace `'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg'` with `'kazvan-1.jpg'` and put the JPEG-file in the same folder as the HTML and JavaScript files.

If this doesn't work, you need to post more code to show what happens to the JSON object you're posting here.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks for the reply and attention! I've tried doing that as you've advised however, it causes the image slider to disappear instead.

Posting more of the code as follows. Hope you could help!

Comment: Remove the trailing slash from here: `'../assets/All_Photos/7-jovin-lim.jpg/'`

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU~ Had such a hard time thinking about that. 

I apologize for the earlier post, have deleted the post and edited on the original question.

Comment: Whoops, Sorry. Just did, new to Stackoverflow here! Have a good day ahead! ^^